# IDA change string in rdata

Tags: ida

This has probably already been asked a million times, but how would I change the `http://iristech.co/custom-code/iris_license.php?`

to`http://fakeliscenceserver.com/`

Thanks.[image]

Comment: That's not a RE question. You an use a hex editor, or a text editor that doesn't ruin binary data, or write a Python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Hex View.
2. Right-click on the data.
3. Choose "Edit..." (Alternatively, press F2).
4. Now you can change the string in rdata.

   - Don't forget to add null terminator.
   - You can just leave the rest of the unused bytes of the original string.
5. Patch the program, go to "Edit", choose "Patch program" and than "Apply patches to input file".